# Create angular component by annotated value?

Tags: angular

When I have two class below

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-image-component'
})
export class ImageComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
...
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-text-component'
})
export class TextComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
...
}
```

Now I should create those components dynamically in a sequence.

It's not difficult for the help of `ComponentFactoryResolver`

```
export class DynamicDrawer {
  let componentListToDraw = ['text', 'text','image', 'text', 'image'];


  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
  }

  drawAll(){
    for(let type of componentListToDraw){
      let factory;
      switch(type){
        case 'image'
          factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ImageComponent);
          break;
        case 'text'
          factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(TextComponent);
          break;
      }

      if(factory){
        let created = this.container.createComponent(factory).instance;
        // now can do some thing for the created component......
      }

    }
  }
```

It is works fine but one point not so nice is if type of components increases `DynamicDrawer` need to changed every that time.

When I works with Java Spring, I could instanciate a component by some annotations. If it possible in angular it would be a great code improvements.

### What I imagine is

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-image-component'
})
@TypeFor('image')  // <--- give some decorator that specify type
                   // refactoring safe, immutable value for the class
export class ImageComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
...
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-text-component'
})
@TypeFor('text')
export class TextComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
...
}
```

And then get the component factory by decorator.

```
export class DynamicDrawer {
  let componentListToDraw = ['text', 'text','image', 'text', 'image'];


  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
  }

  drawAll(){
    for(let type of componentListToDraw){
      // resolve factory by decorator specification.
      factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactoryByDecorator(new TypeFor(type);
    }
  }
```

Is there any way to do this??

Comment: https://blog.angularindepth.com/implementing-custom-component-decorator-in-angular-4d037d5a3f0d This might be a starting step for what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge I do not know if you can instantiate a component by annotation.

An approach that occurs to me by looking at the documentation of angular https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

You could encapsulate the component in a class

```
import { Type } from '@angular/core';

export class DynamicItem {
    constructor(public component: Type<any>) { }
}
```

Then you can do something like this when you iterate it

```
export class DynamicDrawer {
    const dynamicItems = [
        new DynamicItem(MyComponent01),
        new DynamicItem(MyComponent02),
        new DynamicItem(MyComponent03),
        new DynamicItem(MyComponent04),
    ];

    constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

    drawAll() {
        for (let dynamicItem of dynamicItems) {
            let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(dynamicItem.component);
            let created = this.container.createComponent(componentFactory).instance;
        }
    }
}
```